# How to compare array keys' values and insert new array elements into first array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I've two arrays as follows:

```
$grid_data = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [newsletter_id] => 1
            [newsletter_name] => Eywa Solutions
            [newsletter_subject] => Holi Wishes
            [newsletter_email_body] => Happy Holi to all the friends
            [newsletter_call_to_action_status] => 0
            [newsletter_call_to_action_text] => 
            [newsletter_call_to_action_link] => 
            [newsletter_status] => 2
            [newsletter_schedule] => 0
            [newsletter_created_date] => Mar 17 2014, 16:21 pm
            [newsletter_updated_date] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [newsletter_id] => 2
            [newsletter_name] => Akshay Nikte
            [newsletter_subject] => The Don
            [newsletter_email_body] => How are yoy Nikte Saheb?
            [newsletter_call_to_action_status] => 0
            [newsletter_call_to_action_text] => 
            [newsletter_call_to_action_link] => 
            [newsletter_status] => 2
            [newsletter_schedule] => 0
            [newsletter_created_date] => Mar 18 2014, 06:52 am
            [newsletter_updated_date] => 0
        )

)
```

and second array is as follows:

```
 $LastSendNewsletterDetail = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [newsletter_id] => 1
                [newsletter_sent_count] => 5
                [newsletter_sent_date] => 1395121193
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [newsletter_id] => 2
                [newsletter_sent_count] => 7
                [newsletter_sent_date] => 1395121227
            )

    )
```

Now what I want to achieve is compare the key values(named **newsletter_id**) with each other from above two arrays. If they match with each other then insert the data from array $LastSendNewsletterDetail to the first array `$grid_data`. If they don't match then insert blank values to the first array `$grid_data`.

For example the desired ultimate $grid_data array should look like this :

```
$grid_data = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [newsletter_id] => 1
            [newsletter_name] => Eywa Solutions
            [newsletter_subject] => Holi Wishes
            [newsletter_email_body] => Happy Holi to all the friends
            [newsletter_call_to_action_status] => 0
            [newsletter_call_to_action_text] => 
            [newsletter_call_to_action_link] => 
            [newsletter_status] => 2
            [newsletter_schedule] => 0
            [newsletter_created_date] => Mar 17 2014, 16:21 pm
            [newsletter_updated_date] => 0
            [newsletter_sent_count] => 5
            [newsletter_sent_date] => 1395121193
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [newsletter_id] => 2
            [newsletter_name] => Akshay Nikte
            [newsletter_subject] => The Don
            [newsletter_email_body] => How are yoy Nikte Saheb?
            [newsletter_call_to_action_status] => 0
            [newsletter_call_to_action_text] => 
            [newsletter_call_to_action_link] => 
            [newsletter_status] => 2
            [newsletter_schedule] => 0
            [newsletter_created_date] => Mar 18 2014, 06:52 am
            [newsletter_updated_date] => 0
            [newsletter_sent_count] => 7
            [newsletter_sent_date] => 1395121227
        )

)
```

How to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `array_merge` ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: I tried array_merge. But I'm not merging the entire second array into first array. I only want to insert the last two key-value pairs from the second array. Then how should I do this after comparison of newsletter_ids from both arrays? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
for($i=0; $i < $grid_data.lenght; $i++)
{
  $track =0;
  foreach($LastSendNewsletterDetail as $value)
  {
     if($value[newsletter_id] === $grid_data[$i][newsletter_id] )
     {
        array_merge($grid_data[$i], $value);
        $track=1;
     }
  }

  if($track === 0)
  {
  //insert blank value here
  }
}
```